# Google Sheets - Combine multiple IF Functions into one cell

Tags: function, if-statement, google-sheets, ifs

I'm trying to produce a SKU in Google Sheets for a product using the values of three variants *(Title, Colour and Size)*

The product is 'Lightweight trainers' with colour variants of 'Red' and 'Blue', and the sizes range from 5 - 12.

**Link to spreadsheet**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1trq0X3MjR-n2THFnT8gYYlwKscnQavCeeZ8L-ifYaHw/edit?usp=sharing

**Aim**

I'm hoping to have a SKU that displays the product, the colour variant and the shoes size.
Example: `LW-1-8` *(Lightweight trainer, colour Red, size 8)*

Product is Lightweight Trainers with a value of LW.

Colour variant 'Red' with a value of 1 and 'Blue' with a value of 2.

Shoe size variant = number ranging from 5 to 12.

Here's what I have so far, joining the colour and size variants.

```
=IFS(I2="Red",1,I2="Blue",2)&"-"& IFS(K2="5",5,K2="6",6,K2="7",7,K2="8",8,K2="9",9,K2="10",10,K2="11",11,K2="12",12)
```

However, I'm getting stuck in joining the data in column B with this function.

Any help with combining this data from multiple cells into one would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B<>"", IFS(B2:B="Lightweight Trainers", "LW")&"-"&IFS(I2:I="Blue", 1, I2:I="Red", 2)&"-"&K2:K,))
```

### Answer

What you want is basically:

```
<title>-<color number>-<shoe size>
```

To convert this to a function we can split it into each part and take it step by step:

**Step 1: Title**
For the first part -the title- we need to match the value with the shorthand. A simple list in an `IFS` is enough.

```
IFS(B2="Lightweight Trainers", "LW")
```

Obviously for now it only has a single value (Lightweight Trainers) but you could add more:

```
IFS(B2="Lightweight Trainers", "LW", B2="Heavyweight Trainers", "HW")
```

**Step 2: color number**
Similar to the previous step, it’s a mapping using ifs:

```
IFS(I2="Blue", "-1", I2="Red", "-2")
```

The dash is added so when adding everything it will only have it if

**Step 3: shoe size**
In this case we can simply get the value:

```
K2
```

**Step 4: Adding everything together**
We only need to add it with the dashes in between:

```
=IFS(B2="Lightweight Trainers", "LW")&"-"&IFS(I2="Blue", 1, I2="Red", 2)&"-"&K2
```

**Step 5: Extending for the entire column automatically**

We will use `ARRAYFORMULA` to add a single formula to the first cell and get it automatically extended to the entire column. We first add it to the formula we already have, and then extend the ranges to the entire column:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFS(B2:B="Lightweight Trainers", "LW")&"-"&IFS(I2:I="Blue", 1, I2:I="Red", 2)&"-"&K2:K)
```

Remember to remove all the values in the column so array formula doesn’t override them (it would generate an error).

As you can see the formula generates errors for the rows that have no values. A good way of handling this case is to filter the rows without a title. In a single row would be:

```
=IF(B2<>"", [the entire formula],)
```

Notice the last comma.

So putting everything together and extending its range to the column, is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B<>"", IFS(B2:B="Lightweight Trainers", "LW")&"-"&IFS(I2:I="Blue", 1, I2:I="Red", 2)&"-"&K2:K,))
```

Adding this to `N2` should work.

**Final notes**

It seems that you use 150 when the size it’s not a whole number. If you want to keep that functionality you may use:

```
IF(K2-int(K2)=0, K2, 150)
```

On the last component and expand it the same way.

You may also want to prevent having two dashes when a value is missing (`LW-5` instead of `LW--5`). To do so, I’d recommend adding it to each component instead of the formula that adds them together.

### References

- [IFS (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145?hl=en)
- [IF (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)
- [ARRAYFORMULA (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

try in N2:

```
=IFS(I2="Red",1,I2="Blue",2)&"-"& 
 IFS(K2=5,5,K2=6,6,K2=7,7,K2=8,8,K2=9,9,K2=10,10,K2=11,11,K2=12,12)
```

or use:

```
=IF(I2="red", 1, IF(I2="blue", 2, )&IF((K5>=5)*(K5<=12), "-"&K5, )
```

Comment: Thank you for your help -  `=IFS(I2="Red",1,I2="Blue",2)&"-"& IFS(K2=5,5,K2=6,6,K2=7,7,K2=8,8,K2=9,9,K2=10,10,K2=11,11,K2=12,12)` works perfectly to combine the data in columns 'I' and 'K' - How would I combine this with the data (product title) in column 'B'? **Current output example** 2-5 **Desired output example** LW-2-5

Comment: try: `=IF(B2="Lightweight Trainers", "LW-"&IFS(I2="Red",1,I2="Blue",2)&"-"& IFS(K2=5,5,K2=6,6,K2=7,7,K2=8,8,K2=9,9,K2=10,10,K2=10.5, 150,K2=11,11,K2=11.5, 150,K2=12,12)`