# Combine data from multiple IF Functions into one cell

Tags: arrays, function, google-sheets, ifs

I'm looking to create a product SKU by combining the data from columns B, I and K into an SKU in column N). I've managed to combine 'I' and 'K' using the function below but would now like to combine this function with the product title in column B. (Combining Title, Colour and Size and having this replicated for every cell in column N.)

```
=IFS(I2="Red",1,I2="Blue",2)&"-"& IFS(K2=5,5,K2=6,6,K2=7,7,K2=8,8,K2=9,9,K2=10,10,K2=11,11,K2=12,12)
```

The product is 'Lightweight trainers' with colour variants of 'Red' and 'Blue', and the sizes range from 5 - 12.

**Current SKU Example**
2-5 (blue, size 5)

**Desired SKU Example**
LW-2-5 (*Lightweight trainer*, blue, size 5)

**Link to spreadsheet**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1trq0X3MjR-n2THFnT8gYYlwKscnQavCeeZ8L-ifYaHw/edit?usp=sharing

Any help  would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Sheets - Combine multiple IF Functions into one cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65806580/google-sheets-combine-multiple-if-functions-into-one-cell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=IF(B2="Lightweight Trainers", "LW-"&IFS(I2="Red",1,I2="Blue",2)&"-"& 
 IFS(K2=5,5,K2=6,6,K2=7,7,K2=8,8,K2=9,9,K2=10,10,K2=10.5, 150,K2=11,11,K2=11.5, 150,K2=12,12)
```